# Operators precedence in java (unary plus and addition)

Tags: java, operator-precedence

I'm having trouble in figuring out why the output for theses two lines is different ..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println("6.0+1="+6.0+1);
   System.out.println("6.0+1="+(6.0+1));
}
```

**The output** 
6.0+1=6.01 
6.0+1=7.0

Comment: `+` is left associative, so `"6.0+1="+6.0` is the string `"6.0+1=6.0"` and the `+1` concatenates `"1"`.

Answer (score 1):

Your example don't use unary plus.

You use it for string concatenation, and for addition.

`"6.0+1="+6.0+1` will be evaluated in types as *string + number + number*.
So first `"6.0+1" + 6.0` will use `+` as the string concatenation operator, resulting in a new string: `"6.0+1=6.0"`. Then the same happens with the `+ 1` at the end, resulting in another string concatenation.

`"6.0+1="+(6.0+1)` wil first evaluate the `(...)` part, in which you add two numbers, so the result will be `7.0` (floating point + integer => floating type). Then the string concatenation as in the first variation takes place.

Unary operators would work on a single variable/constant/expression, i.e. the unary minus operator as in `x = -1`.

Answer (score -1):

The answers would definitely be different because of the use of Bracket on the second operation,the operation would first start from bracket to other operators.